# java spring shortcut to create dto of an entity with customization ability

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I'm creating a Spring REST API which returns entity JSON differently according to requests.

```
Class User{
  int id;
  String name;
  String address;
  List<Role> roles;
}

@Value
Class UserDto{
   @JsonUnwrapped
   private User user;
}

@Controller
Class UserController {
    public UserDto getUser(int id){...return new UserDto(user);}
}
```

With this approach, I cannot customize the json of the user.

I have to create dto as:

```
@Value
Class UserDto{
  int id;
  String name;
  String address;

  public UserDto(User user) {
      ...copy prioperties...
  }
}

@Value
Class UserDetailDto extends UserDto {
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
    List<Role> roles;

    public UserDetailDto(User user){
       super(user);
       this.roles = user.getRoles();
    }
}

@Controller
Class UserController {
    public UserDto getUser(int id){...return new UserDto(user);}
    public UserDetailDto getUserDetail(int id){...return new UserDetailDto (user);}
}
```

Is there any shortcut/annotation/library that I can use to achieve the same result? I'd like also to know if it's the correct approach to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to use [Jackson View](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation). This allows you to have a different representation of your object according to your API.

```
Class User{
  int id;
  String name;
  String address;
  List<Role> roles;
}

public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }

    public static class Internal extends Public {
    }
}

Class UserDto {
  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  int id;
  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  String name;
  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  String address;
  @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
  List<Role> roles;
}

@Controller
Class UserController {
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public UserDto getUser(int id){...return new UserDto(user);}
    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    public UserDto getUserDetail(int id){...return new UserDetailDto (user);}
}
```

And for your Model / DTO, you can try to look [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) and [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) (based on Annotation Processor) to write less code.

Comment: If I have a view which would like to includes multiple views, how to do it? For example, a view to show name and address, another to show name and roles.

Comment: Create multiple views: Basic (Field name), First extends Basic + Field address and Second extends Basic + Field role

Comment: After creating the 2 child views, how do I create the last view which includes all fields?

Comment: Don't use  the annotation JsonView on your API which have all fields